# When running Windows (or Linux) on a Retina MacBook Pro, what resolution does it report?

Tags: windows, unix, resolution, macbook-pro

I use parallels and vm software to run Windows and Linux on my Apple machines. When running Windows (or Linux) on a Retina MacBook Pro, what resolution does it report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Windows

According to [AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6008/windows-8-on-the-retina-display-macbook-pro):

> Windows 7 by default starts up at 800 x 600 on the Retina MBP, Windows 8 defaults to 1024 x 768. This behavior isn't specific to this system, the **GeForce GT 650M doesn't have native driver support in either OS at this point** and these are the defaults for the standard VGA driver in both cases.
>
> **Windows 7 won't expose any resolutions higher than 1600 x 1200 without an actual NVIDIA driver, while Windows 8 will let you select the full 2880 x 1800 panel resolution**.

This is a report about Windows via bootcamp. I don't know how this differs from Windows being used in a virtual machine. It would probably also depend on the options that the VM software offers.

## Linux

When using the NVIDIA drivers on Linux (and on Windows too) you can select the full native panel resolution (2880x1800). You can also select any of a number of scaled resolutions which don't look as sharp. In general, running at native resolution is actually less of a problem for Linux than it is in Windows and OS X because of the way it's designed. There are no blurry fonts on 3rd party apps like on OS X and it is easier to set your DPI so that apps are scaled properly than on Windows (it is set automatically in Linux).

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread: http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/laptop/476258-howto-2012-retina-display-macbook-pro-opensuse-linux.html

OpenSuSE needs a little help during installation, but after that seems to run at native 2880x1800 just fine. See this comment in particular: http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/laptop/476258-howto-2012-retina-display-macbook-pro-opensuse-linux.html#post2470745

VMware Fusion still doesn't support he resolution very well, here's a workaround until they fix it. http://tumblr.moontrap.net/post/25263035180/vmware-fusion-retina-macbook-pro-linux